# Unable to enable Firebase Invites in iOS on the Firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-app-invites, firebase-invites

I have a Firebase project where I'm using Firebase invites. The Android google-services.json correctly shows App Invites as enabled but the iOS GoogleService-Info.plist file shows it as disabled? Is there a way for me to switch it on for iOS in the Firebase console?

Here's the corresponding parts of the two files:

> **google-services.json**
>
> ```
>     "appinvite_service": {
>       "status": 2,
>       "other_platform_oauth_client": [
>         {
>           "client_id": "4XXXXXXXXXX-r3pppppppppppppppppppppp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>           "client_type": 2,
>           "ios_info": {
>             "bundle_id": "com.experimental.project1"
>           }
>         },
>       ]
>     }
> ```
>
> **GoogleService-Info.plist**
>
> ```
>     <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
>     <false/>
> ```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I just changed the value manually to "true" and it worked. I am not sure why the generated file does not have this enabled correctly.

Comment: I also tried that but it only works for the SMS, but not for mail.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: Try adding App Store ID and Team ID in Firebase Console - Project Settings